# Outlook contact "File as" field value

Tags: mfc, outlook, mapi

How do I programmatically read the default setting for "File as" field for Outlook contacts by a specific user. This is the same info we can get via the **file**->**options**->**contacts** menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the FileAsOrder value in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Outlook\Contact.

0x8017: LastFirstMiddle;
0x8037: FirstMiddleLastSuffix;
0x3A16: Company;
0x8019: LastFirstMiddleCompany;
0x8018: CompanyLastFirstMiddle;

Comment: is there anything you *don't* know?

Comment: I was unable to find this value in regedit..!!

their is no folder with name contact inside outlook..!

Comment: Folder? This is a registry key.

Comment: Ohh..I found..!!
It was under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Contact.
thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me different value of "ConfirmAddress" field ??